# Debugging firestore security rules with emulator does not work

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-tools

I have written some firebase rules, using firebase emulator. I tried to debug the request which I am sending to the rules, using `debug()` function. Yet it doesn't print anything. My rules:

```
function printResource() {
      return debug(resource) || true;
    }

match /users/{userId} {
      allow read, delete: if something....;
      allow create: if printResource() && userIsAuthenticated() && userOwnsResource(userId) && debug(isUserNameAvailable(debug(request))) && getAfter(
          /databases/$(database)/documents/usernames/$(request.resource.data.username)
        ).data.owner == userId;
    }
```

I tried as well the following:

```
match /users/{userId} {
          allow read, delete: if something....;
          allow create: if  debug(userIsAuthenticated()) && debug(userOwnsResource(userId)) && debug(isUserNameAvailable(debug(request))) && getAfter(
          /databases/$(database)/documents/usernames/$(request.resource.data.username)
            ).data.owner == userId;
        }
```

Nothing is being printed. My `debug()` function is not working, but I don't know why. Is there another way I can print my resource object?

Comment: Just to confirm, by printing you mean it is not writing any [results to the “firestore-debug.log” file](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.debug)?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? Still happening 2 years later